# Review my css. Random margins

Tags: html, css, margin

There are random spaces that appear between each of the images.  I wish to have them stick together but i cannot get how to do it, whatever i do...

Html:

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="enconstruction.php"><img src="images/barre3/Environnement Gris.png" class="img1"></a>
<a href="inter.php"><img src="images/barre3/Services publics gris.png" class="img2"></a>
<a href="enconstruction.php"><img src="images/barre3/droits syndicaux gris.png" class="img3"></a>
<a href="mob.php"><img src="images/barre3/mobilisation Gris.png" class="img4"></a>
<a href="index.php"><img src="images/barre3/Home gris.png" class="img5"></a>
```

And the Css:

```
.nav
{
position:fixed;
bottom:-4px;
width:auto;
height:150px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:5;
}

.img1
{
position:relative;
width:180px;
height:auto;
}

.img2
{
position:relative;
width:212px;
height:auto;
}

.img3
{
position:relative;
width:245px;
height:auto;
}

.img4
{
position:relative;
width:218px;
height:auto;
}

.img5
{
position:relative;
width:165px;
height:auto;
}
```

Comment: The line breaks between your `<a>..</a.` count as whitespace and WILL be rendered as a single space. either remove the line breaks, or use html comments `<a>...</a><!-- \n --><a>etc...` or `<a></a><a></a>`

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space in the code. You can get rid of it by:

- Removing the space `</a><a href=...`
- Putting HTML comments between the elements `</a><!-- --><a href=`
- Setting the font size on the parent to zero

Answer (score 0):

The issue is default spacing in `inline` elements (which `img` tags are inherently). There are several methods to correct this. To name a few:

1. You can add `font-size: 0;` to the parent `.nav` - [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhez1y69/)
2. You can do what j08691 suggested and remove the space `</a><a href=...` - [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhez1y69/2/)
3. You can use `float: left` and add `overflow: hidden` to the parent `.nav` to clear the floats - [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhez1y69/1/)